# Overview of MIPS-per-watt?

Tags: performance, cpu, green-computing

I'm looking to buy a 'low energy' system for my home webserver.
One of the main criteria is how much power such a system consumes while providing enough power to run the apps I would like to run.
My current focus goes towards an Atom 230/330 system (Mini-ITX).

I've had a look at http://www.cpubenchmark.net/ to see what the performance of these kinds of CPUs is in relation to the other 'normal' CPUs. Hoeever I've not yet been able to find an overview of the power consumption of both Atom and other CPUs.

Does anyone here know of an overview that can help me make a choice?

Thanks.

Niels Basjes

Comment: tagged "green-computing" for the low-energy focus.

Answer (score 2):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom#Architecture
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core_2#Processor_cores
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Phenom_microprocessors

TDP although actually a measurment of thermal power gives quite a good idea of comparable electrical power consumption at 100% cpu usage.  As you can see something like an Atom or mobile version of a CPU uses a LOT less power than a standard CPU.

Bear in mind that with proper desktop cpus the motherboard draws a lot more power than the low power mini-itx motherboards as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I checked the pages and noticed that in some Atom based systems the chipset uses more power than the CPU. Is there a website somewhere that has an overview of cpu+chipset (or mainboard?) and the benchmark and total energy usage? For Intel, AMD, Via, ARM, etc. ??